# Gatling uri params replacement

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a feeder file that contains following json:

```
 {
    "method": "POST",
    "uri": "/v2/mydata/{timestamp}",
    "payload": [
          {
            "productId": "abcd",
            "timezoneOffset": 420
          }
    ]
  }
```

Following is the Gatling test code that fetch uri,method and payload.

```
val allRecommendationRequestRecords = jsonFile(scenarioAllRecommendationRequests).records


    val allRecommendationPostRequest = allRecommendationRequestRecords.filter(record => record("method").toString.toUpperCase == "POST")
    val allRecommendationGetRequest = allRecommendationRequestRecords.filter(record => record("method").toString.toUpperCase == "GET")

    val totalPostRequestCount = allRecommendationPostRequest.length
    val totalGetRequestCount = allRecommendationGetRequest.length


    /**
     * Triggers
     */

    val triggerForPostRequests = feed(allRecommendationPostRequest.circular)
      .exec(http(simulationTitle).post( "${uri}").body(StringBody("${payload.jsonStringify()}".stripMargin)).check(status.is(200)))

    val triggerForGetRequests = feed(allRecommendationGetRequest.circular)
      .exec(http(simulationTitle).get("${uri}").check(status.is(200)))




val scenarioForPostRequests = scenario(simulationTitle + " post requests").exec(triggerForPostRequests)
    val scenarioForGetRequests = scenario(simulationTitle+ " get requests").exec(triggerForGetRequests)
    var httpProtocol = Recommendation.httpProtocol.shareConnections
    /**
     * setup scenario using weight*
     */
```

Now I want to replace uri **{timestamp}** with a randomUUID().toString

Comment: You should seriously invest some time in reading the documentation: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/#built-in-functions

Comment: No it didn't help that is why asking here. Secondly I am using gatling 2.3 version

Comment: Gatling 2 has been dead for years. You should upgrade. The current version is 3.9.0 as of now.